# SNMP4J bulkwalk on if-mib

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I am using snmp4j.jar. I want to do a snmpwalk on `if-table` to get `ifDescr` from all the rows. Using netsnmp :
`snmpwalk -v2c  -c**** -t 1 1.2.3.4 ifDescr` I can get   ...

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: ATM0

IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: Ethernet0
....
```

I want to do the same with using snmp4j. Any idea how to do that? I followed some tutorial but I am not clear exactly what to do.

Comment: If you followed a tutorial, please provide a link to it and paste here the code you are using. Also, please describe 1. what you expect the code to do, and 2. what it actually seems to do.

Comment: Thank @Jolta ..but i figured it out using http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/util/TableUtils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet of the code . Hope it help someone .

```
public Map<String, InterfaceInfoObject> getTableAsStrings(OID[] oids, String communityString) {
        TableUtils tUtils = new TableUtils(snmp, new DefaultPDUFactory());
        List<TableEvent> events = tUtils.getTable(getTarget(), oids, null, null);
        Map<String,InterfaceInfoObject> indexMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,InterfaceInfoObject>();
        for (TableEvent event : events) {
            if(event.isError()) { 
                throw new RuntimeException(event.getErrorMessage());
            }
            for(VariableBinding vb: event.getColumns()) {
                InterfaceInfoObject infterfaceInfo = new InterfaceInfoObject();
                String oid = vb.getOid().toString();
                String index = event.getIndex().toString();
                String colValue = vb.getVariable().toString();
                    if(indexMap.containsKey(index)){
                        getInferfaceObjectAndsetValues(indexMap, oid, index, colValue);
                    }else{
                        putInferfaceInfoObjInMap(indexMap, infterfaceInfo, oid, index,
                                colValue);
                    }
            }
        }
        return indexMap;
```